# No module named 'discord_components'

Tags: python, pip, discord.py, modulenotfounderror

I work on a bot discord but I cannot import `discord_components`. How can I do that?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import ButtonStyle
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
from discord_slash.utils.manage_components import *
from discord_slash import *
from discord import Member
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions

from discord_components import * # <-- here it fails

from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option, create_choice,         
create_permission
from discord_slash.model import SlashCommandPermissionType
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "botRivality.py", line 10, in <module>
   from discord_components import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_components'
```

What I tried but without success:

```
pip install discord-components
pip install --upgrade discord-components
```

Comment: Whether the module discord-components got installed while you use pip command to install

Comment: "*I try that, but it doesn't work*" "it doesn't work" is meaningless. What was the error?

Comment: `from discord_components import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_components'
` that is the error

Comment: Is this `discord_components` package, a custom package you're developing or some package you're trying to download and use?

Answer (score 0):

maybe pip is not in your environment variables.

you can use `where` python command in cmd to find the path that python is installed in. then you can use this command -

```
[python path] -m pip install discord-components
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73493074/how-to-install-discord-components-in-discord-py) thread.

On this [issue tracker](https://github.com/astrxnomo/discord-ticket-bot-py/issues/7), they suggest that the location of the library we seek is [here](https://github.com/kiki7000/discord.py-components):

"This repository has been archived by the owner on Dec 18, 2021. It is now read-only."

I try to install the project:

```
pip install discord.py-components || python --version
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement discord.py-components (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for discord.py-components                                                                                                         
Python 3.11.6
```

The project's [docs](https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components/guide/getting-started) say:

"If you meet an error No matching distribution found for discord-components when installing, try updating the python version! (It must be upper than 3.6)"

While it may be possible to proceed with finding the legacy library, I'll be evaluating other options, starting with [this](https://interactions-py.github.io/interactions.py/Guides/05%20Components/) alternative.