# How to install discord_components in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I used the command from discord-components "pip install --upgrade discord-components" in cmd and I get this error very time in every python version " No matching distribution found for discord-components" and I have python version 3.10.6.
Please someone can help me?

Comment: I would recommend using discord.py 2.0 instead of an archived plugin library.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install discord-py-interactions
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install cookies-discord-components
```

Works for me